# Test class for Asset trigger doesn't retrieve Product fields

Tags: apex

I have below trigger on after Insert & Update of Assets which is working fine, but test class is NOT.!! The 2 fields which I am asserting, holds null value. While I was researching in the community, I learned that Product Family field of Assets will be evaluated in Run time only and not available within Test class. Is that the case with 'Product Code' field of Assets also? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Trigger**

```
trigger AssetsTrigger on Asset (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
system.debug('Asset Trigger is invoked');
new AssetLineItemTriggerHandler().run();
}
```

**Apex class that gets invoked from Trigger:**

```
public class AssetLineItemTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {

    public override void afterInsert() {
        setAssetProdFamiliesForAccount(Trigger.New);
    }

    public override void afterUpdate() {
        setAssetProdFamiliesForAccount(Trigger.New);
    }

    public override void afterDelete() {
        setAssetProdFamiliesForAccount(Trigger.Old);
    }

    public override void afterUndelete() {
        setAssetProdFamiliesForAccount(Trigger.Old);
    }

    // =====
    // Private functions
    // =====


    @TestVisible
    private void setAssetProdFamiliesForAccount(List<Asset> strAsset) {
        Set<Id> AccIDs = new Set<Id>();
        for(Asset pAsset : strAsset) {
            if (pAsset.AccountID != null) {
                AccIDs.add(pAsset.AccountID);
            }
        }
        if (AccIDs.size() > 0) {
            List<Account> Acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN :AccIDs];
            Util_Account.setProductFamiliesOfAsset(Acc);
            update Acc;
        }
    }

}
```

**Apex Class:**

```
public with sharing class Util_Account 
{
  public static void setProductFamiliesOfAsset(List<Account> Acc) 
    {
        Map<Id,Account> accsWithParentAssets = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, ProductFamily,ProductCode FROM Assets) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Acc]);
        for(Account act : Acc) 
        {
            Account completeAccount = accsWithParentAssets.get(act.Id);
            Set<String> productFamilies = new Set<String>();
            Set<String> ProductCodes = new Set<String>();
            for(Asset ast : completeAccount.Assets) {
                if (ast.ProductFamily != null) {
                    productFamilies.add(ast.ProductFamily);
                    ProductCodes.add(ast.ProductCode);
                }
            }
            act.Asset_Product_Families__c = null;
            act.Asset_Product_Codes__c = null;
            if (productFamilies.size() > 0) {
                act.Asset_Product_Families__c = String.join(new List<String>(productFamilies), ',');
            }
            if(ProductCodes.size() > 0)
            {
                act.Asset_Product_Codes__c = String.join(new List<String>(ProductCodes),',');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Test Class:**

@IsTest
public class AssetLineItemTriggerHandlerTest {

```
@IsTest
public static void setAssetProdFamiliesForAccount() {
    Account a = new Account(Name='testacc1',Country__c = 'Slovakia',ShippingCountry = 'Slovakia',Country_Code__c = 'SK');
    insert a;
    
    Product2 prd = new Product2(Name='Product1', Family='fam1', ProductCode='RMS2345');
    insert prd;
     Asset ast = new Asset(Name='ass1',AccountId=a.Id,Price=100,Product2=prd,Quantity=1,Percentage_of_Maintenance__c=10);
    insert ast;
    a = [select ID, Asset_Product_Codes__c,Asset_Product_Families__c from Account where ID=:a.Id];
    system.assertEquals('RMS2345', a.Asset_Product_Codes__c);
    System.assertEquals('fam1', a.Asset_Product_Families__c);
    
}
```

}

Comment: please define "not working" where does the test class fail?  Use [edit]

Comment: I am sorry, the 2 fields which I am asserting, holds null value. While I was researching in the community, I learned that Product Family field of Assets will be evaluated in Run time only and not available in Test classes. Is that the case with 'Product Code' field of Assets also? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In the "setProductFamiliesOfAsset" method, can you do a system.debug to check if the "accsWithParentAssets" map variable is empty or not after you have initialized it?

Comment: It has Account ID & Asset ID. But ProductCode & ProductFamily are null.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues in the past with these convenience fields on Standard objects that are in effect, formula fields on the related Product2.

A worthwhile experiment is to change this query:

```
Map<Id,Account> accsWithParentAssets = 
   new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, ProductFamily,ProductCode FROM Assets) 
                            FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Acc]);
```

to:

```
Map<Id,Account> accsWithParentAssets = 
    new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id, 
                          (SELECT Id, Product2.ProductFamily, Product2.ProductCode FROM Assets) 
                            FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Acc]);
```

Comment: No it didn't help, I had tried before. Regular code is working fine, just test class doesn't have visibility to Product fields, looks like.!!

Comment: What version is testclass?

Comment: API version is 50.